# JSONArray - how to display using javascript (jsp)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a java servlet to connect to a MS SQL 2008 database and retrieve info, pass the resultset on to a class to convert it to jsonarray and then return that info.

Here is a sample of the returned info when I browse to the class from my browser using http://localhost:8080/KReport/GetInfo?q=va-sql2008 :

```
[{"machineinfo":{"DefaultGateway":"172.24.1.2","groupName":"servers.headoffice.vasa","ChassisManufacturer":"No Enclosure","DhcpEnabled":2,"LoginName":"","MotherboardProductCode":"440BX Desktop Reference Platform","MaxMemorySlots":"15","Machine_GroupID":"va-sql2008dev.servers.headoffice.vasa","timezoneOffset":-120,"ChassisSerialNumber":"None","MajorVersion":6,"MotherboardVersion":"None","MaxMemorySize":"256 GB","Manufacturer":"VMware, Inc.","MacAddr":"00-50-56-9F-00-11","ProductName":"VMware Virtual Platform","agentGuid":871664384736872,"OsInfo":"R2 Server Standard x64 Edition  Build 7600","PrimaryWinsServer":"172.24.1.9","SysSerialNumber":"VMware-42 1f 09 c3 bd 8c ad 60-22 e4 50 1c 35 52 76 fe","OsType":"2008","MotherboardManufacturer":"Intel Corporation","ipv6Address":"[fe80::edf0:d1bd:6ef8:a17d%11]","MachineVersion":"None","IpAddress":"172.24.1.184","DnsServer1":"172.24.1.22","DnsServer2":"172.24.1.29","ComputerName":"va-sql2008dev","ChassisAssetTag":"No Asset Tag","ChassisType":"Other","MotherboardSerialNumber":"None","SubnetMask":"255.255.255.0","MinorVersion":1,"agentInstGuid":"KSY99906876289809604","WinsEnabled":1,"ConnectionGatewayIp":"172.24.1.184","machName":"va-sql2008dev","ChassisVersion":"N\/A","BusSpeed":"0 MHz"}},{"machineinfo":{"DefaultGateway":"172.24.1.2","groupName":"servers.headoffice.vasa","ChassisManufacturer":"No Enclosure","DhcpEnabled":2,"LoginName":"","MotherboardProductCode":"440BX Desktop Reference Platform","MaxMemorySlots":"15","Machine_GroupID":"va-sql2008dev.servers.headoffice.vasa","timezoneOffset":-120,"ChassisSerialNumber":"None","MajorVersion":6,"MotherboardVersion":"None","MaxMemorySize":"256 GB","Manufacturer":"VMware, Inc.","MacAddr":"00-50-56-9F-00-11","ProductName":"VMware Virtual Platform","agentGuid":871664384736872,"OsInfo":"R2 Server Standard x64 Edition  Build 7600","PrimaryWinsServer":"172.24.1.9","SysSerialNumber":"VMware-42 1f 09 c3 bd 8c ad 60-22 e4 50 1c 35 52 76 fe","OsType":"2008","MotherboardManufacturer":"Intel Corporation","ipv6Address":"[fe80::edf0:d1bd:6ef8:a17d%11]","MachineVersion":"None","IpAddress":"172.24.1.184","DnsServer1":"172.24.1.22","DnsServer2":"172.24.1.29","ComputerName":"va-sql2008dev","ChassisAssetTag":"No Asset Tag","ChassisType":"Other","MotherboardSerialNumber":"None","SubnetMask":"255.255.255.0","MinorVersion":1,"agentInstGuid":"KSY99906876289809604","WinsEnabled":1,"ConnectionGatewayIp":"172.24.1.184","machName":"va-sql2008dev","ChassisVersion":"N\/A","BusSpeed":"0 MHz"}}]
```

There are 2 machines listed in there (if you search for machineinfo in there you will find 2 entries). I have verified this returned info on JSONLint and it checks out as valid json.

My servlet returns the info via `response.getWriter().write(njson.toString());` but I can't seem to figure out how to display this info using javascript on another page.

My last attempt was using :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
url:'http://localhost:8080/KReport/GetInfo?q=va-sql2008',
dataType:'json',
type:'GET',
success:function(data){
console.log(data);
},
error:function(jxhr){
console.log(jxhr.responseText);
}

});
</script>
</html>
```

but that didn't work - just a blank screen.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` outputs data to the JavaScript console. If you want to output it to the page then you need to perform [DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML).

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` will output the data to your browser's developer tools. To get it on the page try, in your `success` callback:

```
$('body').append( "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2) + "</pre>" );
```